# Datatable to Access table failure

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I query data from a database and need to put the results into a different, Access database.

I have the code to get the data, fill the datatable and then connect to the new database but I'm not getting the data. The Access table is filled (24000 rows+) but the data is generic and not the data from the datatable.

```
   Dim wTable As New DataTable
   Dim connString1 = "Provider=IBMDADB2;Database=...;"
   Dim connString2 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0..."
   'sWebi is the SELECT query from the 1st database
   'Webi_Connection is the saved connection string = connString1
   Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connString1), adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sWEBI, Webi_Connection)
        adapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
        adapter.Fill(wTable)
   End Using

  Dim insSQL As String = "INSERT INTO tblWEBI_Results (CumbID, CumbIDSequenceNumber, LastName, FirstName, CorrectedBirthDate, Control, Suffix, Account, CustomerPSUnique, CustomerName) VALUES (@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10)"
  Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connString2), adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter, insertCommand As New OleDbCommand(insSQL, DBConnection)
       adapter.InsertCommand = insertCommand
       conn.Open()
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", "CumbID") 
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", "CumbIDSequenceNumber")
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", "LastName") 
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", "FirstName")
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", "CorrectedBirthDate")
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@6", "Control")
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@7", "Suffix") 
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@8", "Account")
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@9", "CustomerPSUnique")
       insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@10", "CustomerName")
       adapter.Update(wTable) 
       conn.Close()
  End Using
```

I get the rows I'm expecting but the data itself isn't displayed.  So, I guess I'm just missing the correct call of the data from the datatable, right?

Comment: Note:  In the first block, your adapter isn't using that connection object.

Comment: Your parameters aren't passing any data other than the quoted strings.  You need to loop through your wTable rows.

Comment: In the first block, I can count the rows after the fill and see more than 24k rows so I know that part is working.  I don't think I want a loop for 24k rows rows because it will take a long time to make the update.  Unless I'm missing how the adapter.Update is supposed to work

Comment: I made a "note" to say you have a conn object in the first block, but you don't use it, so get rid of it.  The way you are doing it, you would have to loop over your 24k rows.  Otherwise, look at [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: You don't use `AddWithValue` or anything like it when you're saving data from a `DataTable`.  You use the overload of `Add` that let's you specify a source column and then, when you call `Update`, the value for each parameter is drawn from the appropriate column in each row.  See here for examples: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872

Comment: Thanks!!  I had looked at some of your older posts about this but just couldn't connect the dots until now!  I corrected my code and double-checked the names of the data I was querying and a few seconds later...24k rows were filled in the Access table!

Comment: Don't put solved in the question.  Put your solution in an answer below.